# I don't get this part in solving the equation $y' = x^2y$

Tags: calculus

First we rewrite the equation $y' = x^2y$ using Leibniz notation:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$

If $y\neq0$, we can write it in differential notation and integrate:

$\frac{dy}{y} = x^2dx$

$\int\frac{dy}{y} = \int x^2dx$

$\ln|y| = \frac{x^3}{3} + C$

This equation defines $y$ implicitly as a function of $x$. But in this case we can solve explicitly for $y$ as follows:

$|y| = e^{\ln|y|} = e^{\frac{x^3}{3}+C} = e^Ce^\frac{x^3}{3}$

so

$y = \pm e^Ce^\frac{x^3}{3}$

We can easily verify that the function $y=0$ is also a solution of the given differential equation. So we can write the general solution in the form

$y=Ae^\frac{x^3}{3}$

where $A$ is an arbitrary constant ($A=e^C$, or $A=-e^C$, or $A=0$)

My question is how do we know that $y=0$ is also a solution of the given differential equation when we assumed that $y\neq0$ and most of all, when $e^C$ cannot be zero since $e^C > 0$

Comment: You know it by inspection of the differential equation you started with in the first place.
Then, you started to find solutions which are not equal to zero everywhere which gave the other solutions.

Comment: I got it. Thanx

Comment: Well, when $y=0$, then $y'=0$ and the differential equation is satisfied obviously. For $y\neq 0$ you derived the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume $y\ne0$, you must also assume (separately) that $y=0$. Then

$$0'=x^20$$ holds.

---

This kind of resolution raises an anomaly that is rarely commented on:

$$\int\frac{dy}y=\log|y|=F(x)+C$$ seems to imply

$$|y|=e^{F(x)+C}$$ or $$y=\pm e^{F(x)+C}$$ with no explicit restrictions on sign variations of $y$, so that for instance

$$\begin{cases}x\in[-3,5]\to e^{F(x)+C},\\x\notin[-3,5)\to -e^{F(x)+C}\end{cases}$$ could be a solution. This is of course nonsensical as the corresponding $y$ is not differentiable, let alone continuous.

The explanation is that we should rather write

$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\log(y)+C\lor\int\frac{dy}{y}=\log(-y)+C$$ and it is not allowed to $y$ to straddle $0$.